# iterating through an array then through another giving strange values

Tags: php, function, foreach

I am passing two arrays to a function, I am then wanting to loop through the first array and check some values against the second. The problem is the second array is giving strange values and breaking the logic. Please could someone point out where I'm being stupid?

the function

```
function completion($check, $values){

$num = count($values);
$i=0;
foreach($values as $a){
    foreach($check as $b){
       if($b[$a] == ''){
          return '<span class="w"><i>incomplete</i></span>';
          break;
       }
    }

    $i++;
}
if ($i == $num);
   return;

}

$values = array('short_bio', 'industry_sector', 'profile_status', 'country', 'locations', 'noe');

$check = ( [row] => 1 [user_id] => 2 [company_name] => mylittlefish [industry_sector] => Automotive / Aerospace [job_title] => Director [profile_status] => [first_name] => Joe [last_name] => Hodgson [package] => [sector] => Catering [recruitment_status] => Keeping an ear to the ground [country] => UK [locations] => Doncaster [noe] => 5 [user_recruitment_status] => [user_endorsements] => [short_bio] => test [previous_job_title] => [summary] => [profile] => [cover] => )
```

if I echo `$b[$a]` i get something like this:

> 612mADJHCKUD5t12mADJHCKUD5t12mADJHCKUD5t12mADJHCKUD5t12mADJHCKUD5t12mADJHCKUD5t6

Hope you can help

Joe

Comment: How are you calling this completeion() function?

Comment: Hi, I'm calling it like this echo $profile->completion($comanyInfo, $values);

Comment: ok what do you expect it to return?

Comment: you are missing commas in $check. Or maybe you could make it a real array like $check = array('row' => 1, 'user_id' => 2, ....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your loop should be :

```
foreach($values as $a){
       if(!isset($check[$a]) || empty($check[$a])) {
          return '<span class="w"><i>incomplete</i></span>';
          break;
       }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: ahhh, so because its not multi-dimensional i dont have to loop through - is that what was generating the random characters?

Comment: Those are memory references I suppose

Answer (score 0):

```
function completion($check, $values){
    foreach($values as $a){
       foreach($check as $b=>$value){
           if($b == $a && $value == ''){
               return '<span class="w"><i>incomplete</i></span>';                   
           }
       }

    }
}
```

or

```
function completion($check, $values){
    foreach($values as $a){
        if (array_key_exists($a,$check) && $check[$a] == '') return '<span class="w"><i>incomplete</i></span>'; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. CompanyInfo array is not defined
2. $check array is missing commas and string values are not enclosed in quotes

   ```
   $companyInfos = array();
   $companyInfo[0] = array( "row" => 1, 
                    "short_bio" => "Painter", "status" => "Single");

   $companyInfo[0] = array( "row" => 2, 
                    "short_bio" => "Designer", "status" => "Married");

    $values = array('short_bio', 'industry_sector',
               'profile_status', 'country', 'locations', 'note');

   foreach($companyInfos as $companyInfo)
   foreach($values as $val)
   {
       if($companyInfo[$val] =='')
        echo '<span class="w"><i>incomplete</i></span>';

   }
   ```